# Microphone boost is always enabled on my head gear

Tags: windows-7, audio, microphone

Although I have the microphone boost explicitly disabled (at zero dB), the headset's microphone is still capturing sounds from the environment at my workplace.

The headset is an A4tech with an approximately 3 inch long microphone stick hard-attached to the head gear. (It's sturdy, good overall quality, and I'm quite satisfied).

I've also spoken with the network administrator to see if there is a group policy enforced with respect to this, but no luck.

The OS is Windows 7 64-bit SP1. These are the Microphone Properties settings:

[image: Microphone Properties Levels]

Comment: It may be in the settings in the program you are using it in, but it may also be that the microphone really is that sensitive.

Comment: Does the program you use have a setting for noise and/or echo cancelling? If yes: Use those. Otherwise try to lower the input gain or sensitivity.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt responses. With the boost disabled, the microphone _does_ act sensitive but i have used other higher- and lower-end microphones and the microphone boost setting in windows has always worked. Only this specific computer with this head gear seems to be the first exception.
Any thoughts?
The computer is a branded old dell optiplex with core2duo processor and front panel microphone and line out jacks.

Comment: The program i use does not have any additional settings like noise/echo cancellation.